# How do I determine both width and angles to cut on my deck

Tags: geometry, mathematical-physics

[image: Picture of deck]

I am trying to figure out how to calculate the length of the board and both cut #1 and #2 angles.

The board will go from bottom left side of deck to top right side.  The far right line is my house.  Nothing should be attached to there.

Answer (score 0):

I think this picture answers the problem:
[image]

The angles are approximately 21 degrees and 69 degrees.  Assuming you are placing a sequence of 2x4's along the deck, I have given a formula for the length of short side of the n'th 2x4